# Web site for XAML snippet sharing?

Tags: graphics, animation, wpf

I am making a game with WPF and C#, and I frequently am in need of artwork for it.  Some things could be easily shared, such as explosion animations, exhaust plumes, etc.  I was wondering if there are any good web sites for this?  All I can find are tutorials and the infrequent sample, but I imagine there is a site out there that I am missing.  I would also like to clarify that I am looking for pure vector based XAML snippets.  I know there are a lot of sites out there for sprites and textures, but I am looking for XAML components that I can tweak.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any sites specifically for this, but the XAML icon pack that comes with VS2010 is a good starting point. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315819/source-for-xaml-toolbar-icons . These are not game related -- but considering how few WPF games there are out there, you gotta take what you can find.

Illustrator makes it very easy to export XAML (Inskscape also has a XAML export feature, but in my experience it's very buggy, borderline useless). There's also [tools to convert Flash to XAML](http://www.mikeswanson.com/swf2xaml/), if you have Flash and prefer that workflow. If you want to go 3D, there's a [XAML exporter for Blender](http://xamlexporter.codeplex.com/) (probably other 3D packages have them too). And don't forget Blend (the trial lasts for a long time!).

Finally, there are also a lot of open-source WPF apps to check out. I'd guess 95% use bitmap rather than vector graphics (mainly because vector rendering *will* slow things down), but some might have XAML graphics. Also, the legality of this is questionable, but if you find a really cool effect in a closed-source app, you can use .NET reflector + [BAML Viewer](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=reflectoraddins) to check it out -- don't copy/paste it, but it can't hurt to look for a little inspiration.